# How to use 'overflow: scroll' with a dynamically sized div container?

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow

I would like to put a large content `<div>` inside a scrollable container `<div style='overflow: scroll'>`. The container should remain the width of its parent (occupy the left panel in the example below), and show a scrollbar if its content is over-sized.

I can't set a `width`/`max-width` on the container `<div>` because it needs to resize as its parent resizes (when the user resizes the window, for example). But now the container `<div>` just grows to fit the entirety of its content, and pushes the page wider than the window, so a scrollbar for the entire page is shown, which is not what I want.

I want the page stay the width of the window, no scrollbar for the page. The container `<div>` stay the width of its parent (the left panel), and show a scrollbar for its content. How to achieve that?

Example:

```html
    <html>
    <body style="display: flex">
      <!-- left panel -->
      <div style="flex: 2">
        <!-- scrollable container, no effect -->
   <div style="overflow: scroll">
          <!-- big child content div -->
         <div style="width: 800px; height: 200px; background: red" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- vertical divider -->
      <div style="width: 1px; background: blue" />

      <!-- right panel -->
      <div style="flex: 3">
        right panel content
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To scrollable container and the parent (left-panel) container add `height: 100%, width: 100%;`. It will resize dynamically according to the parent when given in % and the overflow property will also work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't set `width/max-width` on the container, I am guessing you can still set `max-width` to `parent`(left-panel) of `container`. If yes, you can try setting `max-height:inherit` on `container` after setting `max-width` to left-panel.

```html
    <html>
    <body style="display: flex">


  <!-- left panel -->
  <div style="flex: 2; max-height:100px">
    <!-- scrollable container, no effect -->
   <div style="overflow: scroll;max-height:inherit;">
            <!-- big child content div -->
            <div style="width: 800px; height: 200px; background: red"></div>
        </div>
  </div>

  <!-- vertical divider -->
  <div style="width: 1px; background: blue">

  <!-- right panel -->
  <div style="flex: 3">
    right panel content
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    
</script>

</div><div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div></body>
    </html>
```